# GitLab CI/CD: Faster/more efficient sync file deployment solution possible?

Tags: synchronization, gitlab-ci

We are developing Python scripts locally, check them in into our in-house GitLab which then deploys folders and files (and removals) using rsync to our cloud server.

The relevant step looks like this:

```
rsync \
        --archive \
        --compress \
        --delete \
        --verbose \
        --exclude-from 'exclude.txt' \
        $(VM_BI_SRC_DIRECTORY) $(VM_BI_SERVER):$(VM_BI_DST_DIRECTORY)
```

Due to the amount of folders and small files, this CI/CD pipeline needs about 15 minutes for each change. Likely, as rsync has to determine the delta between the local GitLab folder & files and the remote folder & files, as it is not aware of the actual changes.

Is there a better way for deployment, which just focusses on the "touched" (or removed) files and folders of the merge?

While I searched I have not found a better solution, yet. Any hint is appreciated!

Thank you!

BB@S-Com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a really large directory tree for that amount of run time. Because as long as you don't force the rsync `--checksum` option it does a relatively quick check on mtime & filesize by default.

If you could simply use git on the remote side deployments will be so much faster.. but I guess (remote) access to the on-premise gitlab server is not allowed.

Alternatively you could use git locally to store all changed files, e.g.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD > changedfiles.txt
```

and feed this list to rsync:

```
rsync –-files-from=changedfiles.txt ...
```

so it will only sync the relevant files and not have to traverse through the complete directory tree. That could also save a lot of time.